# SQL Server : primary key vs unique Index

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, unique-index

I have a question about designing a table for events.

Which one is better using a multi-column primary key, or using a sequential primary key with multi-column unique index?

Columns of this table are like this:

[image]

Comment: If you have a PK with **5** columns - be aware that **any** child table wanting to reference this table will **also** need all those 5 columns - which can become a living nightmare, if you have many referencing tables and need to run JOIN query on these.....

Comment: "Which is better" implies asking for opinions and [so] specifically calls those types of questions as off topic. But the answer is, "it depends"; though I doubt that having 5 columns is the correct choice here as there's going to be a lot of duplication of data when you use the key as a foreign key on another table.

Comment: I am sorry, I have not known. This kind of question is off-topic.

Comment: there are not any relationships. this is a single table. I set primary key for just query and   uniqueness

Comment: If it's a single table, then why have an `uniqueidentifier` that *isn't* the primary key? Will there be rows where it will have the same value for the `uniqueidentifier`? If so, that suggests the existence of other tables.

Comment: because of data versioning uniqueness. I need to find data based on sysId and version

Comment: So what is `AggregateId`? Perhaps what you actually want is a single column PK, and then a multi-column unique index/constraint.

Comment: The tips you mentioned were helpful.
thanks for  your time and consideration

Comment: please see this link (May help you):
<https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20204/primary-key-vs-unique-index-performance-difference-with-foreign-keys>?

Answer (score 1):

Generally in SQL Server, PRIMARY KEY is created as unique clustered index in the background.

So, it is good practice to keep clustered index key as:

- Unique (avoids effort to add uniquifier to make the value unique)
- Narrow (does not occupy lot of space)
- Incremental (avoids fragmentation)

So, in your case , it is better to go for

- Sequential Primary key & multi column unique index